# UpsertDE function is not working with raise error function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working on a case where I am updating the DE When a error is occurring.
There are total 100 records in DE where I am making the UpsertDE operation, I can see this code always update the top two records and skip rest of the records.

Here is the code.

```
%%[

set @lookupID = lookupID
set @rows = LookupRows("DDM_MD_Onboarding_Journey_EM_History","lookupID", @lookupID)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
  set @row = row(@rows, 1) 
  set @JourneyExitDate = field(@row,"JourneyExitDate")

IF @JourneyExitDate == '' THEN
  UpsertDE("DataExtension",1,"lookupID",@lookupID,"JourneyExitDate",Now())
  ENDIF
  ENDIF
]%%

%%[
set @sendEmail = 'False'
if @sendEmail == 'False' then
  RaiseError("Do not send", true, 1)  
endif
]%%
```

Is there anything I am missing in the code ?

Comment: Does it behave differently if you remove the RaiseError function?

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj Yes, then it is updating the records.

Comment: Can you try to test with  test/sample Data... I did tried your code and seem to work for me... so I believe the issue might be related to Data! and not with AMPscript

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to specify the fifth Argument in your RaiseError() function. Without it, the data extension records are omitted when skipping.

This would be expected behavior:
https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror/

> 5 Boolean False
> Indicates whether the function preserves Data Extension rows inserted,
> updated, or deleted by AMPscript functions before error occurs, even
> if the process skips the Subscriber. A value of 1 will preserve data
> operations to Data Extensions before the error is raised, even if the
> Subscriber is skipped. A value of 0 does not preserve operations
> before the error.

not 100 % sure on arguments 3 and 4, but I think you can just leave them empty. While you're at it, I am a fan of giving the arguments variable names so someone who's not 100% documentation savvy can understand the raiseError configuration from the code:

```
SET @errorMsg = "Do not send"
SET @skipIndividualSubscriberOnly = true
SET @preserveRows = 1

if @sendEmail == 'False' then
  RaiseError(@errorMsg, @skipIndividualSubscriberOnly,,,@preserveRows)  
endif
```